# HTML code disappears in module backend field after save

Tags: module, administrator, fields

I'm creating a module, where the user posts a HTML code on the backend and it will be rendered on the site page.

However, when I save the module content, the HTML disappear and just plain text is shown, and the HTML is ignored.

**Before Saving:**

[image: before saving]

**After Saving:**

[image: After saving]

I'm creating the field like this, in my component *.xml* file

```
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="basic">         
        <field name="html_code" type="textarea" rows="10" cols="30" />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `filter="raw"` to your XML file:

```
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="basic">         
        <field name="html_code" type="textarea" rows="10" cols="30" filter="raw" />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

> filter (optional) allow the system to save certain html tags or raw data.

<sup>(from https://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type)</sup>